# check if xy[i] matchs any element of an array without forloop

Tags: javascript, match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)
>   [Finding an item of an array of numbers without using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809917/finding-an-item-of-an-array-of-numbers-without-using-a-loop)

i'm wondering if its possible to check if xy[i] matchs any element of an array without using for loop in JavaScript? . with example, please?

thanks

Comment: No. Edit: let me clarify, although you can use wrapper function as mentioned by previous users, the internal implementation will have to use some sort of loops for a dynamic array.

Comment: What's wrong with using a loop?

Comment: edit: in any situation, the code has to loop. My original answer was No, but that wouldn't be accepted.

Comment: This question amazes me every time... Why is it such a bad thing to use a loop?  Put the loop in a function if you're fretting over the beauty of your code!

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a loop or use a function that uses a loop.

Some libraries, like jQuery, offer their own functions (that use loops).

Using a loop is not a bad thing.

You can keep your code pretty (and organized) by putting the loop in a function.

```
var stringArray = [ "one", "two", "three" ];
var searchTerm = "two";

if (contains(stringArray, searchTerm)) {
    alert("found it");
}

function contains(someArray, someTerm) {
    for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
        if (someArray[i] === someTerm) {
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "Using a loop is not a bad thing" thanks alot